# .Net standard library that supports XPath 3.1

Tags: xpath, xquery, saxon, xquery-3.1, xpath-3.1

I'm maintaining a legacy tool of the company I work for written in C# and I'm converting it to .Net standard 2.0. It uses the [Saxon-HE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) processor to process some XPaths and replace some configurations in files.
Its [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE/) on .NET has dependencies that do not allow the execution on all the .Net standard 2.0 compliant platforms (in my case both .Net Framework and .Net core), so I need to replace it with one another tool, better if the standard .Net XPath library.

The problem is that the tool uses some XPaths that perform complex operations such as concatenate strings and select an array item, and I don't know if it's a Saxon-specific syntax or regards a standard.

It is important to know this because if the XPaths are compliant to some XPath standard I could find one another way to process the same XPaths.

Here is some examples:

First:

```
for $row in /Item/SubItem[*]/SubSubItem return(concat($row, \"/ConcatValue\"))
```

Second:

```
/Item/SubItem[*]/SubSubItem/(add[@key=\"TheKey\"]/@value/string(), '')[1]
```

Do you know something about this XPath syntax?

Thank you

Comment: Please check the relevant XPath specs conveniently linked for you from the SO page https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xpath-3.1/info of the tag you have used. And I don't know who would consider using `concat` a "complex" operation in XPath.

Comment: https://github.com/StefH/XPath2.Net claims it supports XPath 2.0 in a way compatible with .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that when you say "Its NuGet package is not .Net standard compliant", what you mean is that Saxon on .NET has dependencies that mean it will not run on all compliant platforms, specifically, that it will not run on .NET Core"? Because the way you've worded it, it sounds as if there is something wrong with the NuGet package, which would be something that is easily fixed.

Comment: @MichaelKay yes, I need this application to run both in .Net framework and in .Net core environments, so all the dependencies used must comply .Net standard 2.0 in order to be executable "everything". Sorry for the mis-worded statement, I'm fixing it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56253091/library-that-supports-some-xpaths#comment99124166_56253091) comment I was able to test [XPath2.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XPath2/) and now everything works. I needed to change only one type of XPath definition

This one:

```
/Item/SubItem[*]/SubSubItem/(add[@key=\"TheKey\"]/@value/string(), '')[1]
```

Changes to

```
/Item/SubItem[*]/SubSubItem/(add[@key=\"TheKey\"]/@value/string(.), '')[1]
```

Please note the additional dot argument of the `string()` function.
This is strange as it should not be require the dot; in fact, per [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-string)

> In the zero-argument version of the function, $arg defaults to the
>   context item. That is, calling fn:string() is equivalent to calling
>   fn:string(.)

but XPath2 complains with this error

```
{"The function 'string'/0 was not found in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2003/11/xpath-functions'"}
```

UPDATE:

After updating the XPath2.Net library to version 1.0.8 the `string()` syntax works.

Comment: It's a bit concerning too that it gives the namespace URI as `http://www.w3.org/2003/11/xpath-functions`, since that is not the namespace used in the final version of the specification.

Comment: As for the zero string argument call, I have filed an issue with a potential fix on that in https://github.com/StefH/XPath2.Net/issues/23 so perhaps you will see a new release fixing that problem.

Comment: I can confirm that with the latest update of the XPath2 lib (1.0.8) the string() syntax works as expected. I update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

The XPath expressions you have given as examples require an XPath 2.0 processor but they are not specific to Saxon.

The expression

```
for $row in /Item/SubItem[*]/SubSubItem return(concat($row, \"/ConcatValue\"))
```

is a `ForExpression`, which is specific to XPath 2.0, and is not easily converted to XPath 1.0 because its result is a sequence of strings, and there is no such data type in XPath 1.0.

The expression

```
/Item/SubItem[*]/SubSubItem/(add[@key=\"TheKey\"]/@value/string(), '')[1]
```

is specific to XPath 2.0 because it uses a parenthesized expression on the RHS of the "/" operator; and again, because it returns a sequence of strings.

I'm afraid I can't advise you whether there exist XPath 2.0 libraries that run on .NET Core, which I assume is your requirement. Saxon cannot be made to run on .NET Core because of its dependency on IKVM, which doesn't support that platform and which (I gather) cannot readily be adapted to do so.

Note that XPath 2.0 is a subset of XQuery 1.0, so you could extend your search to XQuery 1.0 processors as well as XPath 2.0 processors.

**== 2023 Update ==**

SaxonCS 11.x and later run on .NET Core